# URL with /'s in the query parameter - how is it interpreted?

Tags: http, uri

An example of an url with "/" in its query parameter is:

https://forum.en.forgeofempires.com/index.php?forums/announcements.7/

How is this URL interpreted in the back-end?
Is "forums/announcements.7/" a GET parameter?
Is "forums" the get parameter and "/announcements.7/" is just another folder in the next level?

Comment: What back-end? What does this question have to do with Ruby?

Comment: Ok, removed Ruby. What back-end? Assume PHP/Apache for simplicity sakes although not sure it makes a difference. But assume

Comment: It’s totally up to the application, no? Without knowing the specific implementation of the site in question, this can’t be answered.